# Por qué ocurre este error al recargar página en NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nextjs

Tengo una página que muestra una serie de vídeos los cuales se traen de backend dependiendo de las palabras clave buscadas. La primera carga de la página ocurre bien, pero al recargar la página dándole al F5 me salta el siguiente error que no se solucionar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código es el siguiente:

```
const SearchMasterclasses = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  let { t } = useTranslation();
  const options = [
    t("masterclass:filter_option1"),
    t("masterclass:filter_option2"),
    t("masterclass:filter_option3"),
    t("masterclass:filter_option4"),
    t("masterclass:filter_option5"),
  ];

  /** STATES */
  const { kw }: any = router.query;
  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState<string>("");
// El error ocurre aquí, lo que hago es recoger los parametros query de la URL (del tipo /masterclass/search?kw=...), 
  const [keywords, setKeywords] = useState<string[]>(kw.split(" ")); 
  const [videos, setVideos] = useState<IMasterclass[]>([]);
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState<string>(options[0]);

  const sortByFilter = (filter: string): void => {
    switch (filter) {
      case options[0]:
        setVideos([
          ...videos.sort((a, b) => {
            const a_date = new Date(a.createdAt);
            const b_date = new Date(b.createdAt);
            return a_date.getUTCDate() - b_date.getUTCDate();
          }),
        ]);
        break;
      case options[1]:
        setVideos([
          ...videos.sort((a, b) => {
            const a_date = new Date(a.createdAt);
            const b_date = new Date(b.createdAt);
            return b_date.getUTCDate() - a_date.getUTCDate();
          }),
        ]);
        break;
      case options[2]:
        setVideos([
          ...videos.sort((a, b) => {
            return a.duration - b.duration;
          }),
        ]);
        break;
      case options[3]:
        setVideos([
          ...videos.sort((a, b) => {
            return b.duration - a.duration;
          }),
        ]);
        break;
      default:
        setVideos([...videos]);
        break;
    }
  };

  const handleSearchSubmit = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setKeywords([...keywords, keyword]);
    setKeyword("");
  };

  const handleDeleteKeyword = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const keyword = e.target.querySelector("span").innerHTML;
    const new_keywords = keywords.filter((word) => word !== keyword);
    setKeywords(new_keywords);
  };

  const handleKeywordChange = (e: any) => {
    setKeyword(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleFilterChange = (e: any) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setFilter(value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    sortByFilter(filter);
  }, [filter]);

  useEffect(() => {
    searchMasterclasses(kw.replaceAll(" ", "+")).then((res) => {
      setVideos(res);
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (keywords.length > 0) {
      let str = "";
      keywords.forEach((kw) => {
        str += kw;
        str += "+";
      });
      str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
      searchMasterclasses(str).then((res) => {
        setVideos(res);
      });
    } else {
      setVideos([]);
    }
  }, [keywords]);

  return (
    <>
      <Head />
      <main className={styles.main}>
        <h1>{t("masterclass:title")}</h1>

        {/** SEARCH BAR */}

        <div>
          <div className={styles.search_input_container}>
            <h4>{t("masterclass:search_title")}</h4>
            <form onSubmit={handleSearchSubmit}>
              <InputSingleLine
                type="text"
                name="search"
                label=""
                placeholder={t("masterclass:search_placeholder")}
                value={keyword}
                width={140}
                onChange={handleKeywordChange}
                optional={true}
              ></InputSingleLine>
            </form>

            <div className={styles.keyword_list}>
              {keywords.map((word, i) => {
                if (word !== "") {
                  return (
                    <form
                      className={styles.keyword}
                      key={i}
                      onSubmit={handleDeleteKeyword}
                    >
                      <button>X</button>
                      <span>{word}</span>
                    </form>
                  );
                }
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        {/** END OF SEARCH BAR */}

        {/** VIDEOS */}
        {videos.length > 0 ? (
          <div
            className={styles.video_list_container}
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "column",
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "space-between",
            }}
          >
            <InputSelect
              name={"filter"}
              label={t("masterclass:filter_selection_title")}
              title={t("masterclass:select_filter_message")} // Coger de local/es
              options={options}
              width={30}
              onChange={handleFilterChange}
              disabled={false}
              optional={true}
            />
            <div className={styles.search_video_list}>
              {videos.map((video) => {
                return (
                  <ActiveLink
                    href={`${video.id}`}
                  >
                    <div
                      className={styles.video_bg}
                      style={{
                        width: 300,
                        height: 180,
                      }}
                    >
                      <div className={styles.video_details}>
                        <p>{video.title}</p>
                        <p>{`${video.duration} min`}</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </ActiveLink>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <></>
        )}

        {/** VIDEOS */}
      </main>
    </>
  );
};

export default SearchMasterclasses;
```

Es como que al recargar la página no detecta los parámetros detras del ?, y no entiendo por qué en la primera carga si y al recargar no.

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente es por que llega como `undefined` despues de un render, podrías aplicar un valor por defecto para evitar ese error, y poder debuggear el por que está llegado asi

```
const { kw = "" }: any = router.query;
```